# how to store and retrieve images for user articles

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a web site in which users post news to site.
so i have two field in my database `NewsTitle` and `NewsBody`.

The `Newsbody` can have images.

What datatype should I use for `NewsBody`?

I don't want images loaded from image hosting site, I want images save in my database or in my web site's host.
What is the best way to implement this, should I use `ajaxcontroltoolkit`?
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your the datatype as `varchar` as the filename of your image, since all you need to know when you try to display the image is the filename. (but of course, you must already know the location of this file)

Comment: i think you misunderstood, NewBody, has some text and some images as every news on internet.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use `ListView` and the template field will contain asp:image.you can store the image name in the database and bind the imageUrl through the image directory in your system plus the image name.